# javascript timestamp doesn't works in FireFox and in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, browser, time

```
var target_date = new Date("2014-10-12 15:33:08").getTime();
console.log(target_date);
```

I have this little code. In Opera and in chrome it's work fine. 
In firefox and in IE it returns NAN
How can I fix it?

Comment: `Date {Invalid Date}` that's your date parse object generated; try: var target_date = new Date("2014-10-12T15:33:08").getTime();

Comment: @HellBaby you should have posted it as an answer, lol

Comment: **Don't use the Date constructor to parse date strings**. Even the format specified by ECMA-262 ed 5 is not parsed reliably by current browsers. A string without timezone is treated as UTC by most browsers, local by Chrome and NaN in IE 8 (which still has about 20% user share). A simple parser is [*2 lines of code*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154376/efficient-way-to-convert-utc-dates-within-json-array-returned-by-mongodb-in-node/26154431#26154431).